# SVG element drag bounds after transform

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I am using SVG.js to create an element that is draggable. I want to have bounds on the drag. I am struggling a bit with creating a smooth drag boundary handler. I am transforming the point back to the screen coordinates and going from there but its not quite right. I know that the issue is with the x.y when out of bounds. Right now it defaults to the last valid value but it needs to be the lowest/highest x and y for that bound. Not sure how to get that - I think some trig.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/cyberwombat/pen/dzOKGd?editors=1111)

Code:

```
  SVG.extend(SVG.Element, {

   // Get reverse point
   rpoint: function (x, y) {
     return new SVG.Point(x, y).transform(this.screenCTM())
   }

 })

 const draw = SVG('drawing')

 const bounds = {
   minX: 0,
   minY: 0,
   maxX: 250,
   maxY: 250
 }

// Draw outer box
 const rect = draw
  .rect(300, 300)
  .fill('lightgray')
  .back()

// Draw draggable icon
 const icon = draw
  .rect(50, 50)
  .size(50)
  .move(100, 100)
  .rotate(20)
  .front()
  .draggable()
  .on('dragmove', (e) => {
     e.preventDefault()

     const raw = icon.rpoint(e.detail.p.x, e.detail.p.y)

     let x = e.detail.p.x
     let y = e.detail.p.y

     x = raw.x < bounds.maxX && raw.x > bounds.minX ? e.detail.p.x :  icon.point(raw.x > bounds.maxX ? bounds.maxX : bounds.minX, raw.y).x
     y = raw.y < bounds.maxY && raw.y > bounds.minY ? e.detail.p.y : icon.point(raw.x, raw.y > bounds.maxY ? bounds.maxY : bounds.minY).y

     icon.move(x, y)
   })
```

Comment: svg.draggable.js supports constraint objects. Just call draggable with an object defining the box

Comment: Actually its as easy as: `icon.draggable(bounds)` and you are done: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMZPqN?editors=1111